# What is the definition of direct sum of submodules?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Given a ring $R$ and $M_1,\ldots,M_n$ $R$-submodules of an $R$-module $M$, what is the definition of this set?

$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i$$

From where I am reading it seems that it is: $M_1 + \cdots + M_n$ with $M_i$ mutually disjoint. But I read in many places that it is the direct product $M_1 \times \cdots \times M_n$.

So what is it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: By $M_1 + ... + M_n$ I mean $\{m_1+ ... + m_n, m_i \in M_i\}$.

Comment: Conventionally one uses $\oplus$ in things like $M\oplus N$ and $M_1\oplus\cdots\oplus M_n$, and $\displaystyle\bigoplus$ in things like $\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i$.  I edited accordingly.  Also, not that if you type "..." instead of $\ldots$ or $\cdots$, then in LaTeX (as opposed to MathJax, which is used here) you will see something that looks like $A+\text{...}+B$ instead of $A+\ldots+B$ or $A+\cdots+B$, and $A+\text{...}+B$ is incorrect by civilized standards. If you just write \dots then$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$you will see the same thing as if you'd used \ldots if it's between commas and the same as \cdots if its between plus signs or the like. $\qquad$

Comment: @rschwieb : What I called incorrect was the typography in $A+\text{...}+B$ instead of either $A+\ldots+B$ or $A+\cdots+B$, or in $\displaystyle\oplus M_i$ instead of $\displaystyle\bigoplus M_i$. Your comment is on a different subject. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh I see. These differences fell completely below the thresholds of significance, and since you were using words so strong as "incorrect by civilized standards" I was convinced you were talking about something more apparent. My bad

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ("external") direct sum of modules $M_i$ *is* defined as a subset of the Cartesian product of the $M_i$.

Now, there is another thing called the "internal" direct sum of submodules of a module. This is usually defined as the submodules summing to the whole module, and having the property that each component intersects the sum of others trivially. It amounts to each element having a unique representation as a sum of elements from each submodule.

The two are related this way: if you decompose $M$ as an internal direct sum of submodules $M_i$, the internal direct sum is isomorphic to an "external" direct sum via the map $m_1+m_2+\ldots \mapsto (m_1,m_2,\ldots)$.

Conversely, every decomposition of a module as a direct sum of other modules corresponds to an internal decomposition. You just look at the images of the components of the decomposition inside your module, and they form a family of submodules that defines an internal decomposition.

So you see the two are basically the same, it's just that one emphasizes working with tuples of elements in the Cartesian product, and the other works with sums of elements inside the module.

Comment: About the converse claim, say you have an $A-$module decomposition of $M$ into a direct sum of $A-$modules $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}N_{i}$, so you have an $A-$module isomorphism $\phi:M\longrightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}N_{i}$. Yes, it is natrual to define $M_{i}:=\phi^{-1}(N_{i})$, and show that $M$ is the internal direct sum of $M_{i}$'s. I can see how to show $\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}=M$, but how do you show that $M_{i}\cap M_{j}=\{0\}$ for $i\neq j$? This has confused me for a while

Comment: Why is $N_{i}\cap \sum_{j\neq i}N_{j}=\{0\}$? We only assume that $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}N_{i}$ is a (external) direct sum right?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Sorry, you're right, I forgot about the context for a moment.  I'll rewrite

Comment: @JacobsonRadical the condition is $_∩∑_{≠}_=\{0\}$. If $$ is in the intersection, then $()∈_$ (meaning $f(x)$ is zero outside of $N_i$) and $f(x)\in\oplus_{≠}_$, (meaning $f(x)$ is zero on $N_i$). Then from $()=0$ we deduce =0, QED.

Comment: Hm... I am sorry for making this discussion longer and longer, I am really sorry, but I don't get it. So, say $i=1$, we take $x\in M_{1}\cap\sum_{j=2}^{n}M_{j}$, then there exists $n_{1}\in N_{1}$ such that $x=\phi^{-1}(n_{1})$ and there exists $(n_{2},\cdots, n_{r})\in N_{2}\oplus \cdots\oplus N_{r}$ such that $$x=\phi^{-1}(n_{2})+\cdots+\phi^{-1}(n_{r})=\phi^{-1}(n_{2}+\cdots+n_{r})$$. Therefore, we have $$\phi^{-1}(n_{1})=x=\phi^{-1}(n_{2}+\cdots+n_{r}),$$ and since $\phi^{-1}$ is injective, we have $$n_{1}=n_{2}+\cdots+n_{r}.$$ This is all I can get

Comment: what should I do to derive $\phi(x)=(0_{N_{1}},\cdots, 0_{N_{r}})$?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical When you write $n_i$ above, it means "a tuple in the product that is nonzero outside of the $i$th position."  It is an absurdity to say that you could write $n_1$ as a linear combination of the $n_i$'s with $i>1$ unless everything is zero.

Answer (score 3):

A finite direct sum is equivalent to the analogous Cartesian product.  This stops being true for infinite sums/products.

As an example, $(1,1,1,1,1,\dots) \in \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z} \times \cdots$, but $(1,1,1,1,1,\dots) \not\in  \Bbb{Z} \oplus \Bbb{Z} \oplus \cdots$, because elements in the direct sum have only a finite number of nonzero entries.

The product topology and the box topology also capture this distinction.

Comment: This addresses another very common question about sums/products, but not the current question..

Comment: @rschwieb : I interpret "So what is it?" as equivalent to "So which is it?".  To which the answer is, "yes, if the set of summands is finite".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the user is trying to reconcile the difference between the definitions of internal and external direct sums, not finite direct sums and finite direct products. At least, I don't see your solution alluding to the mutually disjoint submodules of a module, as the post outlines. That's just my two cents... I won't be pressing the matter any further

Answer (score 0):

$M_1 + ... + M_n$ with $M_i$ mutually disjoint and $n$ a finite, positive integer 
is exactly $M_1 \times ... \times M_n$ as a set. If you consider them "equipped" with pointwise operations (addition and multiplication with elements of $R$), then they are isomorphic as $R$ modules.

The isomorphism stops being valid, only when we have an infinite number of summands, in which case the direct sum and direct product are different as sets.