# Understanding the decomposition of a module in a sum simple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have the following property for modules:

> Given a right module $M$ and a family of simple submodules $\{N_i:i
>  \in I\}$ such that $\sum_i N_i = M$ there exists a subset $J \subseteq
>  I$ such that $M = \oplus_{j \in J} N_j$.

My question is double:

1. Until this, for me $\oplus_{j \in J} N_j$ means tuples $(n_j)_{j \in J}$ where almost all $n_j$ are zero, but how is this set inside $M$ (perhaps this is an isomorphism?)?
2. Can you provide me examples of this theorem in the usual abelian groups or vector spaces?

Comment: This is an "internal" direct sum. For submodule $N_i$ of $M$ there is a canonical map $\bigoplus_i N_i\to M$ with image $\sum_i N_i$. If this map is injective we say that the sum of the $N_i$ is direct, and can write it as $\bigoplus_i N_i$ if we like.

Comment: You should probably [read this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1691946/29335) for more information about external/internal direct sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, this is the notion of ``internal direct sum,'' which means that $N_j\subset M$, $\sum_{j}N_j=M$, and $\left(\sum_{j\neq k}N_j\right)\cap N_k=\{0\}$ for all $k$.

An example would be for $M=\mathbb{Z}^2$ and the submodules $N_1=\mathbb{Z}e_1$, $N_2=\mathbb{Z}(e_1+e_2)$, and $N_3=\mathbb{Z}e_2$.

Clearly, $M=\sum_iN_i$, but the sum is not direct (why?). However, any choice of two of the $N_i$ is direct:  $$M=N_1\oplus N_2=N_1\oplus N_3=N_2\oplus N_3.$$

Comment: +1 While the original question asked about *simple modules* I don't think it is an important ingredient to the poster's actual question.

Answer (score 2):

For vector space if $V=\sum_{i\in I} V_i$, there exists $J$ such that $\oplus_{i\in J}V_i=V$. This is a classical result which says that a generating family contains a basis of the vector space.